# How to list missing NuGet packages

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package-restore

In a large VS2013 solution the packages.config has got out of sync, and the following message is displayed in the package manager:

[image: Missing NuGet packages]

Is there a NuGet powershell command to list these packages so I can manually remove them from the packages.config?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the solution in Visual Studio. Go to the Solution Explorer panel. Look for the yellow warning signs next to the missing assemblies in under References in your project.

OR

You can try building the solution. It will generate some errors and you can deduce the dlls which are missing.

Comment: If a packages.config entry exists for an unused package (i,e, not referenced) it will also generate this warning.